# Can´t select attributes from xml with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, uml, xslt-2.0

I generate xml from EA Sparx. It wil be input of my transformation, so this is **XML input:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1">
    <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
    <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">
    ...
    </uml:Model>
    <xmi:Extension extender="Enterprise Architect" extenderID="6.5">
    ...
    </xmi:Extension>
</xmi:XMI>
```

I created simple Java program for transformation where I import also external library saxon9he.jar. I think it is library for XSLT 2.0. I created this **XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="windows-1252"  indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="Base" match="/">
        <xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1">
        <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="model"  />
            <xsl:call-template name="extension"/>
        </xmi:XMI>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="model" match="uml:Model">
        <uml:Model>
        xmi:type= <xsl:value-of select="@xmi:type"/>
        name= <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        visibility=<xsl:value-of select="@visibility"/>
        </uml:Model>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template name="extension" match="xmi:Extension">
         extension
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it create this **XML output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
    <xmi:XMI xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1"
             xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1"
             xmi:version="2.1">
       <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
       <uml:Model>
            xmi:type= 
            name= 
            visibility=
        </uml:Model>
             extension
    </xmi:XMI>
```

Why output xml is without selecting attributes? Why they are empty? I can´t find where is problem with xsl:value-of select? Please, help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a named template does not change the current context. Instead of:

```
<xsl:call-template name="model"  />
```

try:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="xmi:XMI/uml:Model"/>
```

Otherwise you will remain in the context of the `/` root node, which does not have any of the attributes you are trying to retrieve.

And then of course the template matching `uml:Model` does not need to have a name.